# how to bind the rows of tibbles together using the bind_row(function"

Tags: r, data-binding, datahandler

So it has been several years since I have done anything With R studio and I cannot remember a thing about it..

I have currently read 12 different CSV files into the console using the read_csv() function for each one respectively and this has given my twelve tibbles.

Now I need to combine these together using the bind_rows() function but I have no idea how to do this. Every attempt I have made has given the error code "argument 1 must have names"

Any help for a novice would be much appreciated.  I have copied 2 parts of my code bellow.

Cheers

**Read the Hereford crime data into R using function read_csv() in package readr**

`read_csv("2019-01-west-mercia-street.csv")`

`read_csv("2019-02-west-mercia-street.csv")`

**bind data frames**

`bind_rows("2019-01-west-mercia-street.csv", 2019-02-west-mercia-street.csv")`

*Error: Argument 1 must have names*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you try to bind two strings together, where the function expects two `data.frames`.

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- read_csv("2019-01-west-mercia-street.csv")
df2 <- read_csv("2019-02-west-mercia-street.csv")

bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

But if I were you, I'd import them all at once with `import_list()` from the `rio` package. Lets say you get all the 12 file names of the csv's with

```
files <- dir(pattern = "csv$")
```

Then you could easily import **and** row bind them with

```
library(rio)
df <- import_list(files, rbind = TRUE, setclass = "tbl")
```

where `setclass` sets the output to a tibble.

Comment: Thanks a lot j3ypi Ill give that a shot.

Comment: If it solved your problem, you can accept the answer.

Comment: Done! sorry, I am new to this site! I shall be looking for some more help later haha